# Why is statements of invoking .then automatically excluded from the for loop

Tags: for-loop, protractor

I tried to loop the elements in an array using for-loop, and then screen eligible elements by two .then statements which are called within the loop body(see the code below), when I ran the code, I noticed that the two .then statements within loop body are not invoked until for-loop end even I defined them within loop body, it means only the last element is passed into .then statement, not screen each element as expected.
please advise how the subsequent .then statements can be executed in each loop. thanks.

```
//get all of opportunity list
commonFunction.getAllTextByXpath(dealWorkspace.opportunityNameXPath).then(function (inactiveOpptyList) {
    //to identify the oppty with permission 'Admin' and status 'On Hold' 
    for (var j = 0; j < inactiveOpptyList.length; j++) {
         var inactiveOpptyName = inactiveOpptyList[j];

         //get permission of the opportunity
         dealWorkspace.getPermissionOppty(inactiveOpptyName).then(function (permission)     {
             if (permission === 'Admin') {
                //get status of the opportunity
                dealWorkspace.getStatusByOppty(inactiveOpptyName).then(function (status) {

                    //take action of Delete opportunity with cancel option
                    if (status === 'On Hold') {
                       inactiveOppty.deleteOppty(inactiveOpptyName, 'Cancel');
                    }
                });
             }
         });
    }
});
```

Two .then functions used in the script above:

```
//get the permission with oppName
dealWorkspace.prototype.getPermissionOppty = function(oppyName) {

return element(by.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'"+oppyName+"')]/parent::*/parent::*/following-sibling::td[@class='permission-td capitalize ng-binding']")).getText();
};

//get the status with oppName
dealWorkspace.prototype.getStatusByOppty = function(oppyName) {

return element(by.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'"+oppyName+"')]/parent::*/parent::*/following-sibling::td[@class='status-td capitalize ng-binding']")).getText();
};
```

Comment: try change `var j = 0` to `let j=0`.  `let` can declare code block scope variable, like `for` code block.  `var` can only declare function and global scope variable.

Comment: The body of your `for` includes Promise which execute async.  When the Promise execute, the `j` has been equal to `inactiveOpptyList.length - 1`, the for loop will be execute only one cycle.

Comment: I changed var j=0 to let j=0. it worked！！thanks for your effective solution and explanation on cause. thank you, thank you very much！